# Bazel copy py_binary output to local

Tags: python, bazel

How do I copy files generated in `bazel run` to my local directory in Bazel? The file is generated in `~/sample_repo/bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/gen_file.runfiles/sample_repo/some_dir/output.txt`. I want to copy that file to the same directory as my BUILD file in local (eg. `~/sample_repo/output.txt`) for check in to VCS. Below are my BUILD file and the python script.

**BUILD**

```
py_binary(
    name = "gen_file",
    srcs = ["gen_file.py"],
)
```

**gen_file.py**

```py
with open('some_dir/output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write('some text')
```

Comment: [Skylib](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib) provides `copy_file`.

Comment: I think `copy_file` still copy within the `bazel-out` directory if I am using it correctly. Do you have any examples that can copy to local path?

Comment: In Skylib you can update the documentation in the source directory by running `bazel run //docs:update`. Implementation [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/d54e8a70ce90a24b921381cbe84fa0b88b22dc46/docs/private/stardoc_with_diff_test.bzl#L49).